# numpy.loadtxt loading floats from single line file when ndmin=1

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7, numpy

**Problem:**
I have a text file containing several numbers. I am trying to grab some of them and load them into arrays. I would like arrays, even when only 1 line is present in the file. I have an issue when there is a single line only. The values are loading as floats and are not loaded into arrays.

**Tried:** From the numpy documentation I would expect arrays of length 1 for the single line text file when using ndmin=1. However, I am still getting a series of floats, see below:

```
>>> ra_deg,dec_deg,l_deg,b_deg=np.loadtxt(args.infile,ndmin=1,usecols=[0,1,2,3],unpack=True)
>>> ra_deg
127.55905
>>> np.__version__
'1.8.1'
```

**Expected:**

```
>>> ra_deg
array([127.55905])
```

Example args.infile input:

```
127.55905 +00.00000 224.77661 +21.83227
```

I am not sure if this is my error, or there is something up with numpy? Any advice before opening a numpy issue would be great, thanks.

Comment: This is pythons unpacking. `loadtxt` returns one array of floats,  which is unpacked to 4 floats.  Try ndmin=2, which should give you a 2d array which unpacks to 4 arrays.

Comment: Excellent, thanks. I tried with ndmin=2 and it works great. I can mark your comment as the answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Just change ndmin=1 to ndmin=2 (in 2nd parameter of loadtxt function), it will give you a 2d array which you want i think.